# Any way to batch stabilize video files?

Tags: video, stabilisation

I have a lot of videos that need stabilization... is there any way to batch stabilize them?

edit: I'm on Windows 7 64-bit. I don't think that what kind of software and footage do I have... I'm just looking for a program that can take a folder full of videos and batch stabilize them. VReveal kinda can do it, but I have to manually add each file to the queue, which is a chore

Comment: Could you maybe add more details? What sort of footage (panning, rotating, from a car, etc...)? What platform? What software do you have? How many footage?

Comment: Do all your video clips need the same kind of stabilization? E.G. in Sony Vegas Pro (video editor) there is a stabilization feature but has numerous parameters to set depending on if the source material is handheld camera, moving object within frame, pan, tilt, etc. It's hard for me to imagine a one stop process that fixes it all. Generally, stabilization is carefully applied in a trial and error manner to allow for each unstable shot to be stabilized.

Answer (score 2):

I think the quick answer is no, not that there is not software to do it, but every clip is different and will need to be stabilized using different paramaters.

If you take the easy way you may realize that after the fact it took way longer in that it could be a step backwards rather than actually helping.

I would recommend editing the clips as is, then stabilize when you are finished, that way it is only stabilizing what is used which is a) faster, and b) more efficient as you may cut around large camera moves that could cause un needed blown up footage.  At this point you could do each clip using software like premiere, which has a 30 day free trial.  And at worst you would just need to apply it individually to each clip, and unless this is a feature, it cant take that much time.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, [Mercalli](http://vegasaur.com/Mercalli) is a standalone tool for Windows that provides batch video stabilization

Comment: Note that this approach does appear to still require choosing some basic settings for each video, but it will run them as a batch operation.